# UITableViewCell subclass's content duplicated

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've got an `UItableViewCell subclass` with this code:

```
#import "RegisterTableViewCell.h"

@implementation RegisterTableViewCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code

        _titolo = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 0, 80, self.frame.size.height)];
        _titolo.numberOfLines = 0;
        _titolo.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        [self.contentView addSubview:_titolo];

        _linearettangolare = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 10, 1, 25)];
        _linearettangolare.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_linearettangolare];

        _input = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(_linearettangolare.frame.origin.x+6, 10, self.frame.size.width-110, 25)];

        [self.contentView addSubview:_input];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    // Initialization code
}



- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

and a `cellforrowatindexath` method written like this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    RegisterTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[RegisterTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.titolo.text = @"Conferma password:";
    cell.titolo.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:13];

    if (indexPath.row%2 == 0) {
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:143/255.0 green:177/255.0 blue:188/255.0 alpha:1.0/1.0];
        cell.titolo.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.linearettangolare.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.input.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        cell.input.secureTextEntry = FALSE;


    }
    else{
        cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:175/255.0 green:209/255.0 blue:227/255.0 alpha:1.0/1.0];
        cell.titolo.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:138/255.0 green:140/255.0 blue:142/255.0 alpha:1.0/1.0];
        cell.linearettangolare.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:138/255.0 green:140/255.0 blue:142/255.0 alpha:1.0/1.0];
        cell.input.textColor =[UIColor colorWithRed:138/255.0 green:140/255.0 blue:142/255.0 alpha:1.0/1.0];
        cell.input.secureTextEntry = TRUE;
    }

    return  cell;
}
```

I've got the following problem:

When my UITableView scroll up and down, after that I add text to inputtextfield, that content "migrates" to another `UITableViewCell`.

What's wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your 'problem' is that the cells are reused and their content is never reset before they are reused.

Either prepare the cells before they are reused with `prepareForReuse` (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableViewCell/prepareForReuse))
or clear the input field in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

According to the Apple guidelines, the preferred way to it (for cell content) is within `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

> For performance reasons, you should only reset attributes of the cell
>   that are not related to content, for example, alpha, editing, and
>   selection state. The table view's delegate in
>   tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: should always reset all content when
>   reusing a cell.

Comment: `- (void)prepareForReuse { [super prepareForReuse]; self.input.text = nil; self.tittolo.text = nil; }`

Comment: if add the line self.input.text = nil, it reset every cell and doesn't maintain content of `UITableviewcell` that I edited before.

Comment: If I want that it keeps the data, is the only way to create a data structure as a `NSMutableArray` to keep already filled `UITableViewCells`?

Comment: Well I'm sure it is not the only way (e.g. you could just avoid reusing cells) but it is the way to go. Your UI should not be your data store - its responsibility is just to show the data but not to hold it.

Comment: Perfect, you answered my question! In fact I asked if it save in some way in cache datas, but it's better to reuse `UITableViewCell` and save in `NSMutableArray` datas get from `UITextField`! Thank you!!